# MKMapView in reverse, when compass mode using in my iphone app project

Tags: objective-c, ios, mkmapview, cllocationmanager, compass-geolocation

I am developing an iphone application,in that app i am showing the client Parking places in different locations on MKMapView. Now I need to use compass mode in MKMapView to show the client parking places in particular direction (SE,SW,NE,NW), for that I run this below code.

```
-(void)updateHeading:(CLHeading *) newHeading  
{ 

  NSLog(@"New magnetic heading: %f", newHeading.magneticHeading);
  NSLog(@"New true heading: %f", newHeading.trueHeading);

  double rotation = newHeading.magneticHeading * 3.14159/-180;

  [mapView setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-rotation)];

  [[mapView annotations] enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop)
 {
    MKAnnotationView * view = [mapView viewForAnnotation:obj];

    [view setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(rotation)];

 }];  
}
```

Everthing works fine in MKMapView, but my MKMapView shows in reverse order, when the device starts rotating, I am facing this problem in ios5 and ios6 also.
NOTE: when I test this app in America, map shows correctly, while I test the app in my location (India) Map turns into reverse.

[image: MKMapView shows reverse map, while device starts rotating.]
`

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You've asked four other questions on this site but not accepted any of the answers. Sooner or later people will stop helping you if you don't join in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the map intended to be centered on the user while rotating? If so you could just set the MKMapView's userTrackingMode to MKUserTrackingModeFollowWithHeading.

If not then how about telling us what you see in magneticHeading, trueHeading and rotation when things go right and when they go wrong.

Comment: i put this line in viewdidload                                  [mapView setUserTrackingMode:MKUserTrackingModeFollowWithHeading animated:TRUE];                                                    but it doesn't make any changes to my map,my map again rotating in reverse,when my device rotates.

Comment: Is it exactly reverse of what you want? Then take out the negative sign from your calculations. If you take out your code altogether, does MKUserTrackingModeFollowWithHeading do what you want?

Comment: how to get the rotation angle of my pin in MKMapView,while i am using compass mode.?